# Can't use metacity themes in gnome flashback session (metacity) Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, 16.04, themes, metacity

I'm using the gnome flashback session with metacity window manager, but I can't change to any metacity theme in any of the tweaking tools, as they're not even appearing in the lists. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GSettings to change theme:
`gsettings set org.gnome.metacity theme THEME_NAME`

Above will work with Metacity 3.16.x and 3.18.x, but starting with 3.20 Metacity by default will use GTK+ theme. To use Metacity themes you will need to change two settings:
- `gsettings set org.gnome.metacity.theme type metacity`
- `gsettings set org.gnome.metacity.theme name THEME_NAME`

Available types are `metacity` and `gtk`. When using `gtk` type Metacity will ignore THEME_NAME and will use GTK+ theme.

Comment: Using the Human theme, this worked for most of my applications. But nautilus and gnome-tweak-tool for example still show the old theme.

Comment: @jpmath Client side decorated windows does not use metacity theme, you need to change GTK+ theme - `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme THEME_NAME`